# Get keys from Object.create

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
Object.keys(Object.create({a:1}))
[]
```

I was expecting `["a"]` as the result.  How do you use Object.prototype / Object.create to ensure the resulting object has its expected keys?

Comment: You may want to use `Object.keys(Object.assign({}, {a:1}))`. In this case, Object.assign will copy keys to an empty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an empty object `{}` as the first parameter, as the prototype, and an array of objects following that, which properties will be copied into the resulting object.

Additionally, every property has to be marked (at least) as enumerable for it to show in the `Object.keys` call

```
Object.keys(Object.create({}, {a:{value:1, enumerable:true}}))
```

This is explained in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) in the *Using propertiesObject argument with Object.create()* paragraph

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  Thanks for heads up on the `enumerable`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Object.create` correctly but please note that this method creates a new object with the specified prototype object (so in yopur case `a` property is set on returned object prototype not the object itself) and `Object.keys` returns only own object properties (properties set on prototype are not taken into account).

You can also use additional `propertiesObject` as second parameter in `Object.assign` and properties of this object will be set directly on returned object. For example:

```
var o = Object.create({a: 'test'}, {b: {value: 'lorem', enumerable: true}})
```

in above code `a` property is defined on `o` object protoype while `b` prop is defined directly on it so `Object.keys(o)` will return `['b']`.

In your case you can use something  like this (empty object as first argument):

```
 Object.create({}, {b: {value: 'lorem', enumerable: true}});
```

but genarlly it doesn't make sence since you can use object literal without using `Object.assign`:

```
Object.keys({a:1})
```

As @AJP mentioned:
*Object.create is really only useful for more advanced use cases defining getter/setter, prototypal inheritance, etc.*

Comment: @RobG Of course you're right. Answer updaed. Thanks!

Comment: This is still only partially true, you CAN add properties to the object itself by passing properties objects to the `Object.create` call, and those will show up from the `Object.keys` call if properly configured

Comment: @alebianco yes you have to use something like:  `Object.create(null, {a:{value:1}})`  I guess Object.create is really only useful for more advanced use cases defining getter/setter, prototypal inheritance, etc.

Comment: @AJP yes, that's his job. Also, after the edit, that line of code `Object.keys(Object.create({}, {a:1}))` is not valid and will result in a runtime error

Comment: Answer updated again.Thank you all for comments and help.

Answer (score 1):

that's because what is in your `Object.keys()` is the object that inherit `{a:1}`
so `a` is not an own property of that object therefore keys will return an empty array